# Which typography questions are off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are questions welcome that deal with typography?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81/are-questions-welcome-that-deal-with-typography)

I've asked a question about [spaces before unit-symbols](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/321/leerzeichen-vor-einheiten), which I know is perfectly valid. But: Which typography related questions are off-topic, and what rules do we apply to distinguish them?

An example of a question I'm not sure about:

- Should I use a thousands-separator in non-tabular presentation of numbers?

Comment: Aw great. Your question made me ask the same thing... I wonder which one will be closed...

Comment: These questions are quite language-specific, so I think we should accommodate them here.

Comment: I vote to close this one, yours is more generic.